# Execute js code after content init using Angular

Tags: angular, typescript

I want to perform some actions in angular 6 app after all contents loaded.
I used `AfterViewInit`, But this code is calling repeatedly when DOM modifies it structure.

Is there any other methods in angular to detect the page load only once ?

Comment: is ngOnInit() not appropriate?

Comment: I suggest looking over this part of the documentation so you can find exactly what you're looking for now and in the future for lifecycle hooks. https://angular.io/guide/lifecycle-hooks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try `ngAfterContentInit()`

> Respond after Angular projects external content into the component's
>   view / the view that a directive is in.
>
> Called once after the first ngDoCheck().

Answer (score 0):

There is the onInit() function that is executed right after the constructor, if that is what you are looking for.
But you could try to run your code on the constructor as well if it is not dom related.